# Why this Type Mismatch?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code:

```
Public Function MultiVLookup(MatchWith As String, TRange As Range, col_index_num As Integer)
    If (MatchWith = "") Then
       MultiVLookup = ""
    Else
        For Each cell In TRange
            a1 = cell.Value
            a2 = CStr(a1) 'FAILURE IN THIS LINE
            b = CStr(MatchWith)
            If (a2 = b) Then
                x = x & cell.Offset(0, col_index_num).Value & ", "
            End If
        Next cell
        If (x = "") Then
           MultiVLookup = ""
        Else
           MultiVLookup = Left(x, Len(x) - 2)
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

and I call it like this:

```
   L_CurrentService = MultiVLookup(L_CurrentCI, Sheets("Servicios").Columns("C"), 2)
```

But it fails in the line marked above with Type Mismatch, and I do not manage to find why.

Why can't I call CStr() like that?

Comment: What is the type of a1?  Call typename on it:

MsgBox TypeName(a1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First note:**

Your function returns `Type mismatch` because you are using argument `.Columns("C")` for `TRange` parametr (for `.Range("C:C")` it works).

In line `For Each cell In TRange`, you actually looping through *columns*, but not cells. That's means that `cell` variable contains entire column.

You can easily check it by adding line `Debug.Print cell.Address` just after `For Each cell In TRange` - you would get message `$C:$C`.

[image]

**Second note:**

Your code is *highly uneffective*..For Excel 2007 and later you would loop through all 1048576 cells. I recommend you to use [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) method instead:

```
Public Function MultiVLookup(MatchWith As String, TRange As Range, col_index_num As Integer) As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim res As String        
    Dim sAddr As String

    MultiVLookup = ""

    If MatchWith = "" Then Exit Function

    With TRange
        Set rng = .Find(What:=MatchWith, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            sAddr = rng.Address
            Do
                res = res & rng.Offset(0, col_index_num).Value & ", "
                Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
                If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Loop While rng.Address <> sAddr
        End If
    End With

    If res <> "" Then MultiVLookup = Left(res, Len(res) - 2)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your for loop to reference the cells.  As of right now it is pulling it in as an array.  To fix do this

```
'add the .Cells to the TRange to reference each cell
For Each cell In TRange.Cells
```

Comment: This solution is more general than the one from simoco, but I chose his (hers?) because it is better explained.

Comment: next time ask for a detailed reason and I will leave one.  I answered why you cant call cstr() like that.